# Where are the server "alternate" installer images?

Tags: 18.04, raid

Long time user of Ubuntu, particularly 14.04 LTS.  Trying to do a fresh install on a new set of HDs with 18.04 LTS.  I have used 14.04 LTS on RAID 1 boot drives and want to do the same with 18.04 LTS.

Historically I've used the "alternate" installer images to create my RAID partitions, etc. because the "standard" installer inexplicably does not support RAID installations, but those images seem to have disappeared from the download site / mirrors some time ago (I think coincident with 16.04 LTS).

Problem is the download page STILL refers to alternate installers and it provides a link that presently points to the 18.04 release directory but there are no alternate installers in that location.

Where are the alternate install images?

If they don't exist, is there another way to install 18.04 over RAID 1?

I am completely content with a text based installer and doing the filesystem layout manually.  I don't want or need a GUI installer.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

You find the Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS **alternate** server images and their checksums at the following link,

**[old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/bionic/](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/bionic/)**

These iso files have the classic Debian installer. 18.04.1 LTS will be updated and upgraded within the original bionic kernel series 4.15.

Example:

- **`ubuntu-18.04.1-server-amd64.iso`** (with the classic Debian installer)
- `ubuntu-18.04.1.0-live-server-amd64.iso` (with the new live installer)

---

The newest version of Ubuntu Server runs a live session and has a new 'subiquity' installer. You find it at the following link,

[releases.ubuntu.com/bionic/](http://releases.ubuntu.com/bionic/)

Comment: That's the link I was referring to!  There are no "alternate" server images in that directory.  I see only server images for each architecture.

Comment: @otto, The first link in my answer contains 'alternate' or classic server iso files, (smaller), `ubuntu-18.04-server-amd64.iso 2018-04-26 18:30 704M`, and the second link contains the new 'live' iso files for the new server installer (bigger), `ubuntu-18.04-live-server-amd64.iso 2018-04-26 19:48  806M` -- I use 'alternate' in the same way as for Lubuntu - with the Debian installer, which is the classic old installer.

Comment: It seems the 'alternate' installer has gone and they now have a new installer. Unfortunately it is not as good and will not allow you to boot from a RAID device (it only makes one disk as booting, and you have to put /boot on to a disk) so it is a backwards step as you no longer have a server that can boot if that specific disk has failed. See this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1785332

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @PaulCrawford. I have updated my answer to make it possible to find the server iso files with the 'alternate' installer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems they fixed it and the download [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.2/release/?_ga=2.91557660.784411243.1560122924-141056204.1549090498) has what appears to be the classic installer. The filename is `ubuntu-18.04.2-server-amd64.iso`.

Unfortunately I am having other problems with it (which I made a [thread about.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149958/ubuntu-server-18-04-2-hwe-kernel-boot-grub-efi-img-file-failed-the-md5-checks)). However, like you, RAID is my reason for needing the classic installer.

I don't know if they serve different pages to different people, but this is how I got to it:
[image: the link to the alternative download page]
[image: the link to the file itself]

I think I recall having your problem a year or so ago and it eventually got better. No idea why they can't keep their links in order.