# Two downloads of Ubuntu Alternative Installer look different (but have same SHA256). How?

Tags: server, system-installation, live-usb, appearance

I am trying to use the Ubuntu Server "alternative installer". I downloaded it from this url: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.2/release/?_ga=2.146670386.784411243.1560122924-141056204.1549090498

On one occasion I [downloaded the iso via http](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.2/release/ubuntu-18.04.2-server-amd64.iso) and a few hours later, I [downloaded 
 the torrent](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.2/release/ubuntu-18.04.2-server-amd64.iso.torrent). Both the http and torrent downloads had identical SHA256 sums, a2cb36dc010d98ad9253ea5ad5a07fd6b409e3412c48f1860536970b073c98f5`a2cb36dc010d98ad9253ea5ad5a07fd6b409e3412c48f1860536970b073c98f5`.

In both cases I created the usb with the command 

`sudo dd if=/home/james/Downloads/ubuntu-18.04.2-server-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=5M conv=sync,noerror`

However, the starting menu looks different between the two installs (same content). Why? If the two files had the exact same hash and were copied using the same dd command, shouldn't the results be 100% identical? What am I not understanding here?

I am also having [other problems with making reliable bootable USBs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149958/ubuntu-server-18-04-2-hwe-kernel-boot-grub-efi-img-file-failed-the-md5-checks), perhaps the problems are related, but I feel like the proximate causes must be different, so I asked separate questions (hope I'm not being rude by asking too many questions in short succession, I have had a bunch of problems in short succession).

First menu screen:
This is the screen I am accustomed to and that I got from the first download
[image: First menu screen:]

With the second download, I got this:
[image: Second menu screen:]
[image: why does this look different?]

So does the installer front page have multiple looks which are chosen according to some cryptic factor?

Comment: It seems to me that you boot 1) in UEFI mode and get the black & white grub menu and 2) in BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode) and get the language selection and then the coloured syslinux menu. This depends on the computer's boot mode: Cloned Ubuntu live systems can boot in both modes. The boot mode is set in the UEFI-BIOS system, which is activated at an early stage of the boot process, before the bootloader of the operating system.

Comment: Yes, I just realized this. I had selected UEFI when it happened but maybe it restarted while I wasn't looking and changed back to regular BIOS. You can post that as an answer. Also, this might be a clue for the other issue I am having https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149958/ubuntu-server-18-04-2-hwe-kernel-boot-grub-efi-img-file-failed-the-md5-checks?fbclid=IwAR2lg9k_ruSI-OBev2s2zGTMwhitnwm_WoIYpU1-j6Zs9C9b6OWWhZXreAc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you boot

1. in UEFI mode and get the black & white grub menu and
2. in BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode) and get the language selection and then the coloured syslinux menu.

This depends on the computer's boot mode: Cloned Ubuntu live systems can boot in both modes. The boot mode is set in the UEFI-BIOS system, which is activated at an early stage of the boot process, before the bootloader of the operating system.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly it. Although I had selected UEFI in the bios, it seems that the bios selection doesn't stick (or follows some cryptic rules that I am not aware of). But as per my other thread, I still have the problem of not being able to verify the integrity of the installer when in UEFI mode.