# Where are the server "alternate" installer images for 22.04?

Tags: raid, 22.04

Basically, I have the same question as : [Where are the server "alternate" installer images?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035073/where-are-the-server-alternate-installer-images) but for 22.04.

I was able to find these for 20.04 in the past (I have them on a USB), although I can't find those anymore either.

To reiterate the question - where are the non-"live" installer images that allow you to install Ubuntu on a Software RAID 1?

Comment: There are no "alternate" installer images with the old style debian installer for the new Ubuntu versions. The newest version is put in a location, that is difficult to find, and it is for Ubuntu Server 20.04 and the mini.iso. It ***is possible*** to install from one of these (that you have already) **and upgrade to 22.04 LTS** (maybe best to wait with upgrade until August, when the upgrade tools are officially released).

Comment: I don't know enough to advice about software RAID 1, but it might be worthwhile to ask the Ubuntu developers at [Ubuntu Discourse](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/) how to do that with the new server versions.

Comment: Everything you needed the Alternate Server Installer for this use should now be available on the standard 22.04 installer -- you can manually partition, drop to a command prompt to copy your EFI partition, setup RAID, and (optionally) setup LVM.

Comment: The 20.04 ones are [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/).